# How to limit impressions for an order in DFP for Small Business?

Tags: google-dfp

I want an ad to have a fixed limit of impressions, say 50,000. I can't find an option to limit that in DoubleClick for Small Business.

**Labels**

I've found [an article](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/7085745) instructing to add limitations with labels but they don't exist in the menu. It may only be available in the premium version.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have the field "Quantity" in the Line Item settings?

[image: Settings - Quantity - Impressions]